# MS Access SQL запрос: Слияние таблиц

Tags: sql, база-данных, access

У меня три запроса по типу этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только в других заполнены либо колонка "На складе", либо колонка "В работе", а все остальные пустуют, также количество записей различается в каждом запросе.

Как объединить значения в таблицах средствами MS Access SQL, чтобы Они были в итоге представлены вот так?

SQL-код трёх запросов:

1:

```
SELECT
    Заказчик.Наименование as Заказчик, 
    Count(*) AS [В работе], 
    Null AS [На Складе], 
    Null AS Смонтировано
FROM (Заказчик INNER JOIN Скважины ON Заказчик.[Наименование] = Скважины.[Компания]) 
INNER JOIN Эксплуатация ON Скважины.[Номер скважины] = Эксплуатация.[Номер скважины]
    WHERE (((Эксплуатация.[Дата остановки]) Is Null))
    GROUP BY Заказчик.Наименование;
```

2:

```
SELECT
    [Отправка заказчику].Заказчик,
    null AS [В работе],
    Count([3_2_1 заказчику].Отправлено-[3_1_в работе].[В работе]-
        [3_2_2 ревизированные].Ревизированные) AS [На Складе], 
    null AS Смонтировано
FROM (([3_1_в работе] INNER JOIN [3_2_1 заказчику] ON 
        [3_1_в работе].Наименование=[3_2_1 заказчику].Заказчик)
INNER JOIN [3_2_2 ревизированные] ON 
    [3_1_в работе].Наименование=[3_2_2 ревизированные].Заказчик)
INNER JOIN [Отправка заказчику] ON 
        [3_1_в работе].Наименование=[Отправка заказчику].Заказчик
GROUP BY [Отправка заказчику].Заказчик;
```

3:

```
SELECT
    Заказчик.Наименование AS Заказчик, 
    null AS [В работе], 
    null AS [На Складе], 
    [3_3_2 все монтажи].Монтаж-[3_3_1 монтаж и эксплуатации].[Монтаж и эксплуатация] AS Смонтировано
 FROM (Заказчик INNER JOIN [3_3_2 все монтажи] ON 
    Заказчик.Наименование=[3_3_2 все монтажи].Заказчик)
 INNER JOIN [3_3_1 монтаж и эксплуатации] ON 
    Заказчик.Наименование=[3_3_1 монтаж и эксплуатации].Заказчик;
```

Comment: Определитесь - таблица или запрос, может проще отредактировать исходные запросы, чтобы оно сразу всё выводило. Не хватает исходной схемы данных.

Comment: Пожалуйста воздержитесь от излишних приветствий, вводных и благодарностей. Вопрос должен быть лаконичным.

Comment: Также советую отформатировать код запросов, чтобы он помещался по ширине. Это сильно упростит его чтение и понимание - т.о. повышая ваши шансы на получение хорошего ответа.

Comment: привели бы Вы лучше структуру таблиц, исходные данные, и что Вы хотите получить, а картинку можно было бы убрать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил основной таблицей сделать таблицу "Закачик", потом к ней подзапросами пристыковал всю необходимую информацию. Без наличия реальных данных, правильность не гарантирую, иллюстрирую идею.

```
SELECT Заказчик.Наименование AS Заказчик, 
  (
  SELECT Count(*) FROM Скважины, Эксплуатация 
    WHERE
      Скважины.[Компания]=Заказчик.Наименование AND
      Скважины.[Номер скважины] = Эксплуатация.[Номер скважины] AND
      Эксплуатация.[Дата остановки]) Is Null
  ) AS [В работе],
  (
//тут второй селект из примера, отдаёт только число.
  ) AS [На Складе], 
  (
//тут третий селект из примера
  ) AS Смонтировано
FROM Заказчик
```

Суть идеи - для каждой строки будут выполняться 3 запроса. Ключевая ссылка на текущее значение имени заказчика - первое условие в WHERE, аналогичная строка должна быть первым условием в каждом подзапросе. Саму таблицу Заказчик добавлять в подзапрос не надо - мы делаем запрос **для текущего заказчика**, пример из первого запроса:

```
Скважины.[Компания]=Заказчик.Наименование
```

Весь остальной запрос максимально укорочен. С этими вырвиглазными названиями и джоинами поступил проще - загнав в WHERE простым равенством. При наличии конструктора запросов натыкивание связей разницы с моей реализацией не даст. Предлагаю простой вариант - делаете параметрический (см. справку) запрос, который спрашивает наименование заказчика и отдаёт ровно одно число.
Потом просто текст этого готового запроса вставляете в глобальный запрос, поменяв параметр на "Заказчик.Наименование" и так три раза.

Еще комментарии по текущим запросам:
1. COUNT() считает просто количество строк, поэтому в корне неправильно отдавать ему результат арифметической операции. Тут по логике правильной будет функция SUM(). Проверьте просто по сырым данным - насколько неправильно на самом деле считает.

2. Дурная практика ссылаться на название заказчика. А если будет 2 заказчика (ИП Иванов И.И.) с одинаковым названием, из разных городов, с разным ИНН и пр.? Добавить ключевое поле в таблицу заказчика

Первый нагугленный док по подзапросам для самопросвещения ("ms access запрос с подзапросом")
http://www.interface.ru/home.asp?artId=16557

Comment: Пробовал, набор полей совпадает и тип данных тоже, но количество записей в каждом запросе разный, т.е.

В одном запросе есть данные по Башнефть и Когалыму,  в другом запросе только по Башнефти, и в итоговом запросе получаются 3 записи вместо 2х

Comment: @ЛевДэва скорее всего Вам надо делать `Group by`, что бы сказать более конкретно приведите пример исходных данных и что ожидаете получить на выходе

Comment: Привел SQL-код трёх запросов в топике.

Comment: Мне кажется ему нужен JOIN ?

Comment: Сумел придумать реализацию на подзапросах. Вообще на данном этапе развития уже можно поизучать VBA или более серьезные технологии.